# {WilliamChart} How to update the ChartView's maximum value for y-axis?

Tags: android

At the moment I am developing an app that shows the user some ChartViews to visualize stored values. If the user clicks a button the DataSet gets dismissed and a new DataSet will be added to the ChartView. This already works.

My question is: How can I update the ChartView's maximum value for the y-axis?

Right now the View gets the new DataSet including the new values, but if the values are much higher or lower, the ChartView should scale to the new values.

For example: I had values [4,6,3]. Now i dismiss these and add a new DataSet [9,12,10]. The ChartView should now scale to the new values (old max (6) to new max (12).

How can I do this? Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

You have to use

```
chartView.setAxisBorderValues(newMin, newMax, step);
```

to achieve what I described above.

I actually went through the commands several times, but didn't find it until 2 minutes ago. Blind ... :)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time for iterating through possible methods :)