# How to set the range X axis and Y axis in William chart android

Tags: android, charts

I am embedding a  line chart view in android . The plot is drawn over a dataset of three months of stock of an IPO . The chart is drawn nicely but the values on X axis and Y axis gets very clumsy. Is there  a way i can set the range of X axis and Y axis . Am using William Chart library to draw the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set scale your chart

```
chartView.setAxisBorderValues(newMin, newMax, step);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30688437/1853912